# $L\{f(x)\}^{-1}=\int^x_a \frac{dx}{f(x)}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, improper-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

> let $a<b\in \overline {\mathbb R}$ such that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$, Let $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb R$ be continuous and positive on $(a,b)$
> $$L\{f(x)\}^{-1}=\int^x_a \frac{dx}{f(x)}$$
> Where $f(x)^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f(x)$.
> $\int^x_a \frac{dx}{f(x)}$ is defined on $[a,b]$ and $L\{f(x)\}$ is defined on $\Big[0,\int^b_a \frac{dx}{f(x)}\Big]$.

This construction, applied on the equation of a circle, i.e. to $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ gives the sine function, as shown below
$$
L\Big\{\sqrt{1-x^2}\Big\}=\left(\int^x_{-1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)^{-1}=\sin(x),
$$
For $f(x)=\sqrt{(1-k^2x^2)(1-x^2)}$, it gives the elliptic function
$$
L\Big\{\sqrt{1-k^2x^2}\Big\}=\left(\int^x_{\frac{1}{k}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-k^2x^2)(1-x^2)}}\right)^{-1}$$
Applied to the equation of the hyperbola it gives hyperbolic functions
$$
L\Big\{\sqrt{1+x^2}\Big\}=\left(\int^x_{0}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)^{-1}
$$
**Question**: does this construction has a geometric representation?

I am asking this since, due to the known property
$$
\frac{dr}{dx}= \frac{1}{\dfrac{dx}{dr}}\iff f'(x)= \frac{1}{\big(f^{-1}(x)\big)'},
$$
if $f(x)$ is integrable, calling $F(x)$ an antiderivative of $f(x)$, this implies
$$
L\big\{f(x)\big\} = F(p)\big|^{p=f^{-1}(x)}_{p=f^{-1}(0)}
$$

Comment: In the last example you show, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=+\infty$, which is against construction.

Comment: If you elaborate more where you are trying to get, i could help

Comment: The only "noticible" thing i found is that if $f$ is differenziable, then $\textit{L}\{ \frac{f(x)}{f^{\prime}(x)} \}=( \log(f(u))|_a^x )^{-1}$, and other possible "generalizations".

Comment: Someone should help the OP to formulate an understandable question that transmits his ideas.